# Protecting a file with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis

How do I secure one aspx page with basic authentication, in a website running IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012)? The Forms authentication is used elsewhere on the website, but I need a temporary protection to this particular file with Basic Authentication.

In IIS, I have disabled anonymous authentication on the folder where the file resides, and enabled the Basic Authentication. I have also created the new local user, and given it permissions to read the folder. I would like to use this username/password to access the resource.

Yet, I can access the file without seeing any user name/password prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below:

1. On the IIS Manager application, access your website and select the directory that you want to protect.
2. On the right part of the screen, access the option named: Authentication.
3. Disable the Anonymous authentication on the selected directory.
4. Enable the basic authentication on the selected directory.
5. In this example, i configured the IIS server to use the basic type of authentication and configured the IIS server to require authentication to access a directory. As an administrator, create a local user account.

   `net user /add xxxx`

To test the installation, open the browser and try to access the protected directory. Enter the URL in the Browser, the IIS server will require you to perform the user authentication.